# Is it possible to change similar items using php?

Tags: php, replace

For example, i have something like this:

`<i id="text">text</i><br><i>text2</i>`

and I want to change it to something like this:

`<b>text</b><br><i>text2</i>`

so it will keep the `<i>text2</i>`

but change the `<i id="text">text</i>` into `<b>text</b>`

is that even possible?

Comment: Absolutely, using regular expressions. Sorry I can't be of much further help - I hate writing them! Just thought I'd chip in with where to start looking.

Comment: the complexity of code depends on the variance of your input data. Can you show more input examples?

Comment: @AndyBursh Well, not so fast... are HTML comments, CDATA sections, and other inline elements and PHP sections and other things allowed inside the `i` element?  If so, then use an HTML parser....

Comment: @Ray you have a point! I'm taking the examples provided as gospel as it stands; though I'd agree if you said that's maybe not a great idea.

Comment: @Ray HTML parser? Does PHP have one? If you mean XML parser then it will choke on OP's example because of that `<br>` without the ending tag.

Comment: @AndyBursh thanks a lot i just didn't know what to search for. that gave me a great boost

Comment: @nobody, you are right that an XML parser would choke on the OP's post but there is no reason why an HTML parser could not be written; it is just a little more complicated than one for XML.  I was only trying to point out, without linking to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags that if the `i` tag was very complex (e.g. has arbitrary nesting) than a simple regex will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there are no nested `<i>` tags, this should do the trick:

Input regular expression: `<i id=".*?">(.*?)</i>`

Replacement: `<b>\1</b>`

```
$output = preg_replace('/<i id=".*?">(.*?)<\/i>/i', '<b>\1</b>', $input);
```

Untested, but it should work.

Comment: Watch out for the `/i` inside the regex delimited by slashes.

Comment: Great now double up the backslashes because they are in php strings.  Otherwise you get "Unknown modifier '>' :)

Comment: @Ray: um... no, why would that happen?

Comment: Oops, I blindly put the following into http://writecodeonline.com/php/: `$input = '<i id="text">text</i><br><i>text2</i>';
$output = preg_replace('/<i id=".*?">(.*?)<\/i>/i', '<b>\1</b>', $input);
echo $output;` and got the error.  If you are not iterpreting the code then what you have is good. +1

Comment: thanks! this helped a lot! however this made everything load incredibly slowly (i actually intended to do this on links, but i thought my link example won't make sense) because there was like 400 links or so

Answer (score 0):

This recursive regex works with any levels of nesting:

```
function regReplace( $str ) {
    return preg_replace_callback( '/<i id="text">(.*?(?R)*)<\/i>/is', 'replaceTags', $str );
}

function replaceTags( $matches ) {
    return '<b>'.regReplace( $matches[1] ).'</b>';
}

var_dump( regReplace( '<i id="text">text <i id="text">text <i id="text">text</i></i></i><br><i>text2</i>' ) );
```

result:

```
<b>text <b>text <b>text</b></b></b><br><i>text2</i>
```